# Spring Data Couchbase and Spring Data MongoDB at the same time use

Tags: spring, spring-data, couchbase

I want to use Spring Data Couchbase and Spring Data MongoDB at the same time.
But it has error happen, they both hava bean **customConversions** is defined.
So, how deal it?

This is stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.CustomConversions cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.convert.CustomConversions
    at com.*.*.config.dev.DevelopmentCouchbaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64a18d5.customConversions(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.config.AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration.couchbaseMappingContext(AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration.java:157)
    at com.*.*.config.dev.DevelopmentCouchbaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64a18d5.CGLIB$couchbaseMappingContext$13(<generated>)
    at com.*.*.config.dev.DevelopmentCouchbaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64a18d5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7675b050.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at com.*.*.config.dev.DevelopmentCouchbaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$64a18d5.couchbaseMappingContext(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 65 more
```

Comment: Could you provide the error info and stacktrace?

Comment: OK, I edit it. @jeffrymorris

Answer (score 4):

I find way:

Just override and rename the bean.

this is Couchbase config:

```
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration {
    @Override
    @Bean(name = "couchbaseConversions")
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CustomConversions(Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

and this is MongoDB config:

```
public class MongoDBConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {
    @Override
    @Bean(name = "mongoDBConversions")
    public CustomConversions customConversions() {
        return new CustomConversions(Collections.emptyList());
    }
}
```

Thanks.